# How can to perform the following SQL query using the ORMan orm?

Tags: android, orm

I'm using [ORMan](https://github.com/ahmetalpbalkan/orman/wiki) ORM library on my Android project.

How can I perform the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE my_column is null
```

The point of difficulty is the **is null** part.
I would to like to use the lib to build the query instead of put the SQL by hand.

Comment: Can you please check my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803804/how-to-use-orman-library-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could always call

Query q = new Query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE my_column is null")

Else, I think C.custom("my_column is null") would do.

Comment: Yes, i've done both of your suggestion and it works, but I thought that it was possible to build the query using the framework, using something like isNull(..), but apparently there aren't. Also it's not possible to fetch a list of values taken from a column, but you can only fetch a single value, which is a strong limitation for me. Maybe I will have to implement my own.

Comment: On the absence of responses and solution from my own research I will check your answer as the correct. Thank you!

Comment: np. still, i think it is funny there is no actual way to make such request.

Comment: Can you please check my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803804/how-to-use-orman-library-in-android