# How to use ORMan library in android?

Tags: android, database, orm

I want to use you ORMan library in android for my app. I googled a lot but was unable to get proper tutorials for this.

I just need some useful links which can give my detailed idea of ORMan.

> Can anybody please provide me some helpful links? which can take me to
>   integrate ORMan in my android app.

Comment: https://github.com/ahmetalpbalkan/orman/wiki

Comment: @Sunny Thanks for reply but I have already gone through it, looking forward for other tutorials